# Xamarin forms update Label in Xalm file from another cs file

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have 5 files :

- MainPageViewModel
- MainPage.cs
- MainPage.Xalm
- MyWordPage.Xalm
- MyWordPage.Xalm.cs

My problem :

I would like to update the visibility of a Label in MainPage.Xalm when clicking on a button in MyWordPage.Xalm.cs

Here my MainPageViewModel :

```
bool myfirstmenuvisible = true;
public Command<bool> PrimaryMenuVisibleCommand { get; }


    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        PrimaryMenuVisibleCommand = new Command<bool>(OnprimaryMenuVisible);
      
    }



    public void OnprimaryMenuVisible(bool MyBoolValue)
    {
        MyFirstMenuVisible = MyBoolValue;
        
    }

 


    public bool MyFirstMenuVisible
    {
        get => myfirstmenuvisible;
        set
        {
            myfirstmenuvisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
```

Here is MyWordPage.Xalm.cs

```
void OnMyButtonClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            MainPageVM.PrimaryMenuVisibleCommand.Execute(false);
        });
    }
```

Here is my MainPage.Xalm where I want to update :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage >

       <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Label Text="you can see " IsVisible="{Binding MyFirstMenuVisible}"></Label>
    </ContentPage>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: it is generally a bad practice to have one page directly modify another pages view.  A better idea would be to use something like `MessagingCenter` to pass a message from one page (or VM) to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like jason said,you can use `MessageCenter` to solve the problem.I wrote a demo ,and it works well on my side.

First, you can send message to the subscriber in the viewmodel of `MyWordPage.Xalm.cs`, just as follows:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, bool>(this, "false", false);
}
```

Second, in the viewmodel of `MainPage`, you can subscribe the message and here is the code :

```
public class MainPageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public bool myfirstmenuvisible = true ;
        public bool Myfirstmenuvisible {
            get
            {
                return myfirstmenuvisible;
            }
            set
            {
                if(myfirstmenuvisible != value)
                {
                    myfirstmenuvisible = value;          
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Myfirstmenuvisible));
                }
            }
        }
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, bool>(this, "false", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Myfirstmenuvisible = arg;
            });
        }
    }
```

At last,we can bind the `Myfirstmenuvisible` to the label in the `MainPage.xaml` :

```
<Label Text="you can see "  IsVisible="{Binding Myfirstmenuvisible}"></Label>
```

For more details, you can check:
[Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) .

Comment: Please when I add MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "false");  after MessagingCenter.Subscribe  in public MainPageViewModel()

The message is note displayed